# How to fetch value of dynamic control in button click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a web page which has dropdownlist and button control.List contain subject code.After selecting subject code,dropdownlist selected index get fire.After selecting subject code,fetching subject name from database.
In that event,I am showing dynamic control like textbox and label control based on subject code.
Assigning that subject name value to dynamic label control.User are allow to enter mark of subject into dynamically added textbox.
Onclick of add button,I want add dynamically added label and textbox value.
into database.How to fetch dynamically added control's value in button control event?

I am sharing my code below

```
protected void ddlSubject_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        TableRow NewRow = new TableRow();
        TableCell NewCell = new TableCell();
        Label newLable = new Label();
        newLable.Text = dr["SubjectName"].ToString();


        NewCell.Controls.Add(newLable);
        NewRow.Cells.Add(NewCell);

        TableCell NewCell2 = new TableCell();                         
        TextBox txtBox1 = new TextBox();

        NewCell2.Controls.Add(txtBox1);
        NewRow1.Cells.Add(NewCell2);
        tblLanguages.Rows.Add(NewRow1);
    }
}
```

Comment: A picture would really help describe issue, as is its really hard to understand

Comment: You can use `Request.Form["control ID here"]`, provided you have some logic to retain the ID of the dynamically created control.